# What are the best practises to handling errors in trigger called functions?

Tags: postgresql, error-handling, triggers

I am currently writing dwh loaders which get data from restapi then mainly inserts from database to database. There is log table with after insert trigger which call a "starter" function which starts the loading functon(s). So basically:

API -> check that last loading has FINNISHED succesfully -> insert to table -> insert to log table -> trigger (wait for FINNISH status) -> starter function -> loading function.

But i afriad that if something goes wrong with the procedure and it rolls back the full transaction (or at least there wont be finnished status)

Currently i use:

`exception when others then`

However im curios that is there any other error handling for trigger called procedure? Do you have any best practises?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Never use `WHEN OTHERS THEN`. That will "swallow" errors you don't want to miss, like data corruption or other unexpected runtime events.

Normally, you shouldn't handle any exceptions in your trigger. Instead, write good code that does not cause an error under normal circumstances. You want that trigger to succeed, right? Under normal circumstances, you *want* the operation to fail if the trigger has a problem.

If you have to, catch and handle specific exceptions that are to be expected under ordinary circumstances.

Comment: I use `when other then` with logging into a  log table. But thank you for the warning.